# ST_Rotate in geometry Vs ST_SetRotation in raster

Tags: raster, postgis, gdal, postgis-2.0, postgis-raster

I have one polygon geometry (Square to be precise). I tried to rotate that geometry via `ST_Rotate()`. Then I stored that same geometry in a raster and tried to rotate the raster with `ST_SetRotation()`.
The values were different in both cases.

I am assuming `ST_Rotate` does rotation around the point (0,0) by default
and `ST_SetRotation` doesn't.

Is there any reason for this implementation
and can I achieve the same result I am getting
in geometry rotation in raster rotation as well?

Comment: [Traditionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file), affine transformations on raster data use the *center of the top left cell* (pixel) as origin. The reason for that implementation is *unified raster data definition* vs. *arbitrary linear algebra*.